# iOS : unsigned long with big factorial

Tags: ios, unsigned, factorial

I'm trying to make factorial method like the following

```
-(void)getFactorial{
    NSString *numStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _maxTF.text];
    max = strtoull([numStr UTF8String], NULL, 0);
    for (unsigned long i = 1; i< max ; i++) {
        unsigned long factorial = [self factorial:i];
       if(factorial <= max){
          NSLog(@"%lu (%lu!  =  %lu)",i ,i ,factorial);
       }else{
          break;
       }
    }
}

-(unsigned long) factorial:(unsigned long)n
{
    if (n==0) {
        return 1;//TODO make it empty
    }
    else
    {
        return n*[self factorial:n-1];
    }
}
```

and it's simple and work fine.. till I try number like (18446744073709551615)
which by all means should stop when i = 20, but the factorial of 21 is actually smaller than factorial of 20, so it go on till it reach zero.

I can't figure out where is the problem exactly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factorial is larger than the `usigned long` will allow, causing an overflow (starting at 0 again) making it appear to be smaller.

Comment: so what is the solution.. I have to use unsigned long .

Comment: You cannot compute 21! with an `unsigned long`; it just won't fit. You can provide error checking to make sure the user does not give a number that is too large, but you cannot compute it. (An approximation can be made with a floating-point type, but you said you want `unsigned long`)

Comment: What is the largest number you need to factorial to work for? `25!` ? `30!` ?

Comment: Does it need to be exact?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87427/discussion-between-iliketau-and-mohamed-emad-hegab).

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using an unisgned value, the multiplication results in an overflow.  That is why 21! looks smaller than 20! in your application.

log2(21!) = 65.4, so unsigned math is just throwing out the higher order bit.

Comment: so what is the solution .. I have to use unsigned long for this issue

Comment: An unsigned long (64 bits) just isn't big enough to hold 21!.  Depending on what you intend to do with the answer, you could either use a floating point type (double or float) or some type of bignum library.  Floating point will be easier to work with, but won't give an exact answer.  A bignum library may be slower, but will give you the precise answer.  It really depends on what you intend to use the answer for.